# Find when scroll go on bottom and when go on top

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a div in the main page. In that div I have a scroll and I want to do some action when the scroll go on bottom and go on top .

I write this code for do this work:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("scrollMe") public myScrollContainer: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
  }
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
}
```

and html code:

```
<div #scrollMe class="mainscroll"></div>
```

but this is have a problem . when user load the page its automatic go on bottom but i sont want this . i want when user scroll and arrival to the bottom it do some work and when user scroll and arrival to top do some work .

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2xwybf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**how can I solve this problem ????**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don't want to create directive, then you can simply handle the **(scroll)** event of your div. Something like this

```
<div style="height:300px; overflow:auto;" (scroll)="divScroll($event)">
<p>Some Text</p>
<p>Some Text</p>
....
</div>
```

And handle the event in component. Something like this

```
  public divScroll(elem: any) {
 //the scroll height calculation logic shall remain the same.
  }
```

Please find the working [stackblitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ijh7cu?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Answer (score 0):

You want to know when the user has reached the **top** and **bottom** of the scrollbar. For this you'll have to listen to the **scroll** event of the of the div. The best approach for this is to create a **directive** and bind that **directive** to the underlying **div**.

Secondly, the **scrollTop** property of the element tells you **at which position currently your scrollbar is**. This is how your **scroll event** would look like

```js
  @HostListener("scroll", ["$event.target"])
  onScroll(elem) {
    if (elem.scrollTop == 0) {
      alert("reached at top");
    }
    if (elem.scrollTop + elem.clientHeight >= elem.scrollHeight) {
      alert("reached at bottom");
    }
  }
```

Please find the sample [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qniptm?file=src/app/app.component.html).

P.S.

**[scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight):** total height of the content your element is covering.

**[clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)** the inner height of an element in pixels (based on its css styles). Please find a [good discussion](https://medium.com/@jbbpatel94/difference-between-offsetheight-clientheight-and-scrollheight-cfea5c196937) on these

Comment: Please find my another answer that solves the same problem without the use of directives.